# Tizen Tv Automation

Tags: automation, nunit, robotframework, tizen-tv

I am beginner with Tizen automation, C# and .Net. Appologies if my question sound very basic.

I need to develop a test automation for Tizen TV and perform UI automation for simulating remote control commands, Get the elements Id’s and perform click action.

I am able to get element Id’s using Web inspector by installing application on TV simulator available with Tizen Studio.

I got sample reference from https://samsung.github.io/Tizen.CircularUI/guide/CreatingTestAutomation.html for automating .Net Applications using C#, NUnit Framework in Visual Studio.

Below is the code I tried

```
  namespace TestTizen
  {
   public class Class1
    {
      private TizenDriver<AppiumWebElement> _driver;

      [SetUp]
      public void SetUp()
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Connecting to Appium server");
         AppiumOptions option = new AppiumOptions();

         option.AddAdditionalCapability("platformName", "Tizen");
         option.AddAdditionalCapability("deviceName", "emulator-26101");
         option.AddAdditionalCapability("appPackage", "org.tizen.sample0008.Filesystem");
         _driver = new TizenDriver<AppiumWebElement>(new Uri("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), option);
    }
    [Test]
    public void ClickAction()
    {
        _driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=\"info container\"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]").Click();
    }
}}
```

The code has no errors but the connection with the Appium server is not getting established. It would be really helpful if anyone can help on how to execute the Test case.

Also please let me know if there is any way to make this possible with Robot Framework. Since, we primarily use Python and Robot Framework for Automation in our project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like two separate questions to me.

Comment: my actual requirement is tizen TV automation.Any approach would be helpful. Asked about robot framework since my team uses python primarily.

Comment: Unfortunately, https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/Smart-TV/FAQ/FAQ.html says "Test automation (such as with Appium) for the application is not available, because sdb shell is not available." Note that the CircularUI guide you referred to in the question is for watch devices.